# When i click ajax tab control it shows one rectangle box how to remove in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, ajax

i did tab control in  ajax but when i click or open page that time it shows one blue color rectangle box i need to remove that one how can i remove

Comment: That "blue box" looks like it is just your browser highlighting the link you clicked.  Clicking somewhere else on the page will make it go away.  But as far as I know, there isn't a way to make the browser stop doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always uses this property:

```
outline: none;
```

Comment: where can i take that `outline:none;`

Comment: I think I am a bit confused here ! Do you host this in an online place ? If yes please give me the URL.

Comment: I checked this `outline: none;` where i have to add this at last i got Thank you